# How to pass ".*" as an argument to the program in visual studio code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, command-line

I am coding a program in C++ where I want to pass ".*" (period and asterisk) as an argument to the program. I use the Visual Studio Code editor which might be causing this problem unless I do not know enough about command-line.

Below is my `launch.json` for visual studio code.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [".*", "ajiaugbfal"], // I am sure I am doing this correctly
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}\\",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mgw\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when debugging in visual studio code, that argument appears differently as shown in the image below. ".*" should appear as the value stored in the variable `arg_pattern` (in the pane on the left under variables).
[image: Debugging screenshow]

I have attached my code for reference.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>


using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;


void clear_istream() {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}


class Solution {
public:
    bool isMatch(string arg_string, string arg_pattern) {
        if (arg_string.length() == 0) return false;
        string::iterator iterator_string = arg_string.begin();
        string::iterator iterator_pattern = arg_pattern.begin();
        char character_previous = '\0';
        while (iterator_string != arg_string.end()) {
            if (iterator_pattern == arg_pattern.end()
                && iterator_string != arg_string.end()) return false;
            if (int(*iterator_pattern) >= int('a') && int(*iterator_pattern) <= int('z')) {
                if (*iterator_string != *iterator_pattern) return false;
                character_previous = *iterator_pattern;
                iterator_pattern = iterator_pattern + 1;
                iterator_string = iterator_string + 1;
            } else if (*iterator_pattern == '.') {
                character_previous = *iterator_pattern;
                iterator_pattern = iterator_pattern + 1;
                iterator_string = iterator_string + 1;
            } else if (*iterator_pattern == '*') {
                if (character_previous == '.') return true;
                while (*iterator_string == character_previous) iterator_string = iterator_string + 1;
                iterator_pattern = iterator_pattern + 1;
            } else if (*iterator_pattern != *iterator_string) return false;
        }
        if (iterator_pattern != arg_pattern.end()) return false;
        return true;
    }
};


int main(int arg_count_arguments, char **arg_arguments_command_line) {
    string input;
    string pattern;
    Solution solver;
    int index = 0;
    /* if you are trying in VS Code, comment the loop and return statement right under.
When using VSCode debugger. Put a breakpoint whenever solver's "isMatch" is called. 
Proceed step-by-step to check the value of "arg_pattern".
if you are using command-line pass: .* random_stuff.
    */
    while (index < arg_count_arguments) {
        cout << arg_arguments_command_line[index] << endl;
        index++;
    }
    return 0;
    index = 2;
    if (arg_count_arguments < 3) {
        cout << "Pattern ?: ";
        cin >> pattern;
        cout << endl;
        clear_istream();
        while (cin >> input) {
            cout << index << ' ' << solver.isMatch(input, pattern) << endl;
            clear_istream();
        }
    } else {
        while (index < arg_count_arguments) {
            cout << index << '-' << solver.isMatch(arg_arguments_command_line[index], arg_arguments_command_line[1]) << endl;
            index = index + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Insight: So .* actually causes the program to fetch the name of the first   folder(or directory) in the directory of the program. I.e if there is a folder (named: `name_folder`) on the top of the directory in which the program is located, .* passed to the program on command-line refers to `name_folder` and the name is passed. So, how to pass .* ?

Comment: Program just stops and waits for input when I run it. You should consider backing up your program, modifying it to use a hard-coded input set that exposes the bad behaviour you're looking for help with, and replacing the current example with the input-free program. That way everyone examining your program is working on the exact same problem.

Comment: Good on you for using the debugger, by the way. Far too many people waste their time by not using one.

Comment: thank you for your comment, let me see how I can improve.

Answer (score 1):

Got similar ploblem with `*` in a path which I tried to pass as an argument in `launch.json`.

Here is what I found working for me and also your case.

```
"args": ["path=./data/*/images"] -->
"args": ["path=`echo \"./data/*/images\"`"]

"args": [".*"] --> 
"args": ["`echo \".*\"`"]
```

`` `cmd` `` – tells bash to execute the `cmd` inside of the string.

`echo "string"` – prints `string` to the standard output.

`\"` – escaping `"` because we are already inside of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, the * is a glob match for any number of characters. To avoid this, just escape the asterisk to avoid it being a glob: `".\\*"`.

[glob man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) for additional info.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately, I tried and it did not work. In fact, I tried to expand on your input, none of these worked: \\.\\\*, \\.*, \.*. They all have an undesired effect to adding backslashes.

Comment: Ok, it works if I compile it using cygwin g++ but not mingw g++... How does this work? I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

So as per my initial research behind this, it did not seem possible to do it. Thank you to **SuperStomer** to discover compilers have an effect.

Cygwin g++ won't have the problem but MinGW g++ seems to have. The least troublesome argument when using MinGW is "\.*", instead of passing ".*" as an argument, it seems to work with the least modification I.e only one '\'.